# Is it safe to use header() to protect/secure a page?

Tags: php, authentication, http-headers

Simple question really. Can I use this to safely shield a page?

```
user-only-page.php:

if (isLoggedIn() == false) header('Location: login.php');
```

isLoggedIn() returns true or false depending on weither the user is logged in or not.

- Or is there a way to ignore this header?
- Should I maybe force an `exit;`?

Comment: or use `die('Custom Simple Error Message');`

Comment: Could you elaborate? Why is this necessary?

Comment: @SuperSpy its necessary because simply issuing a header doesn't stop the script from executing. Code further down will still run unless you explicitly `exit` or `die`.

Comment: As in, the rest of your 'Protected Content' may still get displayed and if the client is for some reason ignoring headers then they'll get the content they shouldn't be seeing.

Comment: Could you write this in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header command is executed by the browser rather than the server, so using header relies on the users browser being complicit with your wishes.

When the page is sent to the browser, the content following the header directive is also sent, so the user has access to the remaining content.

With php, you can force the script to end using the exit (or die) function. So the following is good practice:

```
if (isLoggedIn() == false) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}
```